# Comparing ordinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, ordinals

I'm trying to teach myself set theory, and know that for any two ordinals $α$,  $β$, exactly one of $α ∈ β$,  $α = β$, $β ∈ α$ hold.

The notes I'm working have an exercise which asks me to determine which of these holds when

> (i) $α = (ω + 1).2$, $ β = 2.(ω + 1)$
>
> (ii) $ α = (ω + 1).ω$, $ β = ω.(ω + 1)$

but I haven't seen any examples where this has been done, and having messed around with the definitions of ordinal arithmetic haven't been able to put the pairs in forms I can easily compare.

Any help you could offer would be really appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! What forms have you come up with in the two cases? It may be that you've done everything just right, and are missing something. It may be that you can't easily compare them because you've done something wrong. Seeing your attempts and efforts will make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Each ordinal represents a well-ordered set, two isomorphic well-ordered sets are the same ordinal. Which ordered set is represented by $(ω + 1).2$, does it contain the one represented by $2.(ω + 1)$ ? (the [rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Multiplication) give $1+\omega=\omega, 2.\omega=\omega<\omega.2= \omega+\omega, \omega.\omega=\inf \{a, \forall n, \omega.n<a\} $)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to offer a more "order-oriented" approach:

$(\omega + 1) \cdot 2$ is the order where we replace every point in $2$ by a disjoint copy of $\omega +1$, so that's $\omega$, a maximum so far, $\omega$, total maximum; the maximum after the first copy can be seen as part of the second copy of $\omega$, so in total we get $\omega+\omega+1$.

$2\cdot (\omega+1)$ is the order where we replace each point of $\omega+1$ by a copy of $2$, so a doubling of points. The initial $\omega$ gets replaced by a new copy of $\omega$ , the final maximum gets doubled, so that's in fact $\omega+2$ as an ordinal, and this is an initial segment of the previous order from the first paragraph.

Try now to visualize why $(\omega+1) \cdot \omega$ is smaller than $\omega \cdot (\omega+1)$. E.g. $(\omega+1) \cdot \omega$ is $\omega$ in which we replace each point by $\omega+1$. but the final max in $\omega+1$ is "eaten up" by the following copy of $\omega+1$ as *its* minimum, so the result is just $\omega^2$ in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Some useful facts to keep in mind are that addition and multiplication of ordinals is associative, $n\cdot \omega = \omega$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N^{+}}$, and $\alpha \cdot 2 = \alpha + \alpha$. We also have a left distributive law, $\alpha\cdot (\beta + \gamma) = \alpha \cdot \beta + \alpha \cdot \gamma$, but not a right distributive law.

For (i), we have $(\omega + 1)\cdot 2 = (\omega + 1) + (\omega + 1) = ((\omega + 1) + \omega) + 1$
$$ = (\omega + (1 + \omega)) + 1 = (\omega + \omega) + 1 = \omega\cdot 2 + 1$$

On the other hand $2\cdot (\omega + 1) = 2\cdot \omega + 2 = \omega + 2$

Hopefully it is clear that $\omega + 2 < \omega\cdot 2 + 1$. Therefore $(\omega + 1)\cdot 2 > 2\cdot (\omega + 1)$.

For (ii),
$$(\omega + 1)\cdot \omega = \mbox{sup}_{n < \omega} (\omega + 1)\cdot n$$
$$= \omega^2 + 1$$

On the other hand
$$\omega\cdot (\omega + 1) = \omega^2 + \omega$$

Hopefully it's clear that $\omega^2 + 1 < \omega^2 + \omega$. Thus $(\omega + 1)\cdot \omega < \omega \cdot(\omega + 1)$

Comment: $ (\omega+1)  \cdot \omega=\omega^2$